# NSE vs SE in mutate_

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I've been reading and reading, but I cannot understand this NSE vs SE in R. I hope somebody can explain it properly.

```
df=data.frame(a=1:6,b=7:12,c=13:18,d=rep(c("a","b"),each=3))
```

This is what I'm used to, and it works:

```
df %>% group_by(d) %>% mutate(new=sum(a))
```

Now I'm into new territory, this works, but throws a warning. Can somebody explain to me how I'm to do this if not with group_by_?

```
var="d"
df %>% group_by_(`var`) %>% mutate(new=sum(a))
```

> Warning message:   group_by_() is deprecated.  Please use group_by()
>   instead

Now, onto what I'm really trying to do, this just throws an error:

```
var="d"
var2="a"
df %>% group_by_(`var`) %>% mutate_(new=sum(`var2`))
```

> Error in sum(var2) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

I'm really trying to understand the fundamentals here... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [book on Tidy Evaluation](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/) is a fantastic resource to learn about NSE. You may find [Chapter 8](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html) particularly useful.

In your case, you need to first convert your character strings into symbolic variable names:

```
s1 <- sym(var)
s2 <- sym(var2)
```

If you were to use `s1` and `s2` in dplyr directly, it would attempt to look for columns named `s1` and `s2` in your data frame. This is not what you want. Instead, you want to access the symbols stored **inside** the variables `s1` and `s2`. You can do this through the unquoting operator `!!`:

```
df %>% group_by( !!s1 ) %>% mutate( new=sum(!!s2) )

## Or putting everything together
df %>% group_by( !!sym(var) ) %>% mutate( new=sum(!!sym(var2)) )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Nice explanation!

Comment: Would it be the same using !!s2 or !!sym(var2) in your last line of code?

Comment: Yes, in this example the two are equivalent.

Comment: I just want to follow up and say this was so useful for my everyday programming, very grateful! :)